I am confused about a certain property of spinor transformations that seems to be inconsistent based on my current understanding.
I am considering the transformation of a two dimensional Weyl spinor $\lambda^\alpha$ given by a matrix transformation of the form $p(\lambda)^\beta = \lambda^\alpha m_\alpha^{\ \ \beta}$. Let's say that I want to consider the transformation of the dual spinor $\lambda_\alpha$.  According to my understanding (see Penrose and Rindler "Spinors and Spacetime", pg. 115, for example), the dual spinor transforms as $p(\lambda)_{\beta} = \lambda_{\alpha} [m^{-1}]_{\beta}^{\ \ \alpha}$.  However, if I consider lowering the index directly, I find
\begin{equation}
p(\lambda)_\beta = p(\lambda)^\gamma \varepsilon_{\gamma \beta} = \lambda^\alpha m_\alpha^{\ \ \gamma}\varepsilon_{\gamma \beta} = \lambda^\alpha m_{\alpha \beta} = -\lambda_\alpha m^\alpha_{\ \ \beta}.
\end{equation}
The last equality comes from "index swinging" the $\alpha$ index, which gives the negative sign.  I have not assumed anything about the matrix $m$ that would imply that $[m^{-1}]_\beta^{\ \ \alpha}=-m^\alpha_{\ \ \beta}$.  This seems to be a contradiction, but I'm sure it just arises from some misunderstanding I have regarding the calculation that is being done here.  Any clarification would be very helpful.  Thanks so much in advance!

I actually think that I figured this out.  It is actually the case that for two-dimensional matrices, we have the formula $[m^{-1}]_\beta^{\ \ \alpha} = -\frac{m^\alpha_{\ \ \beta}} {\det{m}}$, which one can verify by explicitly raising, lowering and transposing indices.  The $\det{m}$ discrepancy comes from the theory, (I am using Penrose and Rindler for this).  In the discussion, he is considering a basis change where the determinant is sometimes normalized.  In the case where it is not, the Levi-Civita symbol is actually scaled by the determinant, which is where the discrepancy comes from!

If anyone knows of a reference for that inverse formula, please share, I derived it but haven't found a good reference.  I've seen a formula for the determinant using Levi-Civita symbols though.
